# Problems finding a Botton on BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to click a button on a webpage, but I can't find the href. My code is the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome() 
ref = 'https://www.leychile.cl/Consulta/buscador_experto'

browser.get(ref)

python_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button'][@value='Buscar']")
search_box = browser.find_element_by_name("palabra_frase")
search_box.send_keys("Alcaldesa")
time.sleep(1)
python_button.click()
page = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source) 
continue_link = page.find_element_by_link_text('Siguiente')
```

In this new webpage, I am trying to click on the button "Siguiente"

When I inspect the webpage there is the following href

```
<a href="javascript:Paginar2(87)"> Siguiente › </a>
```

but BeautifulSoup is not showing me that button so I can not do the click.

Comment: That's not a button, it's an anchor. What does it have to do with the XPath in your code?

Comment: You're looking for the button with Selenium, not BS.

Comment: The XPath on my code is just to go to the webpage that I actually want to scrape, that is the one with the results from the search "Alcaldesa"

Comment: OK, but you need to post the code that's trying to find the `Siguiente` anchor after you go to the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change pages you can do the following:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
ref = 'https://www.leychile.cl/Consulta/buscador_experto'

browser.get(ref)

python_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='button'][@value='Buscar']")
search_box = browser.find_element_by_name("palabra_frase")
search_box.send_keys("Alcaldesa")
time.sleep(1)
python_button.click()
browser.execute_script("javascript:Paginar2(2)")
```

### Explanation:

When you inspect the code you see there's a javascript script that changes pages in this portion of code:

```
<span class="avanzar_resultados" name="paginador2" nitemsporpagina="10" 
pagina="1" totalitem="1781">1 - 10 de 1781<a href="javascript:Paginar2(2)"> 
Siguiente › </a><a href="javascript:Paginar2(179)"> Última » </a></span>
```

So you can call it. For an arbitrary page you just call:

```
browser.execute_script("javascript:Paginar2(n)"
```

### Test:

If you then run:

```
page = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
page.find('span', {'class':'uppercase'}).text
```

You get `'\nDecreto 743 EXENTO\n'` (page 2) instead of  `'\nResolucion 65 EXENTA\n'` (page 1)